# How to rewrite URL according to a condition?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I was trying to get URLs edited in Apache as described below however I have not been successful.

If the URI starts with letter 'a' and third digit is not '7' with total digits are 6
then url `http://example.com/a/123456/` should be rewritten to `http://example.com/sixdigits.php`

If the URI starts with letter 'b' and third digit is not '7' with total digits are 4 then url `http://example.com/b/1234/` should be rewritten to `http://example.com/fourdigits.php`

Here is what I have tried with the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^a/[0-9]+/$  sixdigits.php 
RewriteRule ^b/[0-9]+/$  fourdigits.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another regex variant:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^a/\d{2}[^7\D]\d{3}/?$ sixdigits.php [L]

RewriteRule ^b/\d{2}[^7\D]\d/?$ fourdigits.php [L]
```

- `[^7\D]` will match any digit except `7`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^a/([0-9]{2})([012345689])([0-9]{3})/?$ sixdigits.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^b/([0-9]{2})([012345689])([0-9])/?$  fourdigits.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `[^7]` to indicate `NOT 7`
- `\d` to indicate `[0-9]`
- `{2}` etc. to indicate `two of the preceding character`

Consequently:

> If the URI starts with letter `a` and third digit is not `7` with
> total digits are 6 then url `http://example.com/a/123456/` should be
> rewritten to `http://example.com/sixdigits.php`

```
RewriteRule ^a/\d{2}[^7]\d{3}/?$  sixdigits.php
```

> If the URI starts with letter `b` and third digit is not `7` with
> total digits are 4 then url `http://example.com/a/1234/` should be
> rewritten to `http://example.com/fourdigits.php`

```
RewriteRule ^b/\d{2}[^7]\d/?$  fourdigits.php
```

Comment: Sorry, but `[^7]` is not suitable to match _a digit_ that is not seven.

Comment: @arkascha Aha. Are you saying there's a difference between the character `7` and the digit `7`?

Comment: No. That is not what I am saying. Your pattern accepts any charater except for the "7", but the OP wants to accept only digits except for the "7". That is something different. You accept letters for example which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @arkascha Ah. Yes, I take your point. I wrote the above solution on the basis that the chance of the URL being `/a/12h456/` approximated to zero. I understand that you're saying (and understood when I wrote the solution) that this URL would represent a false positive. But I also concluded that accounting for this would represent a [premature optimisation](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: I disgree. Not so much because of the chances of such a URL getting requested (we both know _nothing_ about that...). But because your pattern makes the implementation hard to maintain. It does not implement what is intended. That never is a good idea. But those are just my 2 cents...

Comment: @arkascha I think your opinion is entirely valid. I think there is a good case for replacing `[^7]` with `[012345689]`. I also think it's possible that, later on, a careless subsequent coder might misread the latter as `[0123456789]` and mistakenly optimise it as `[0-9]` or `[\d]` (a mistake they are unlikely to make on reading `[^7]`) but I acknowledge you do raise important concerns, nevertheless.